# Geodesics given a metric

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Could anyone remind me how find the null geodesic of a spacetime with metric $$ds^2=f(x)dt^2+dx^2$$?

What is the "parameter"?

Thank you.

---

Or in general just any geodesic?

Comment: Have a read of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity).

Comment: Are you speaking about The Roberstson Walker spacetimes? If it is so you can find a good reference in the book of Barret O'Neill 'Semiriemannian geometry'

Answer (score 1):

*Null geodesics*: take the time $t$ as parameter, and observe that the null-geodesic $x(t)$ must satisfy $x'(t)^2=-f(x(t))$. Of course, $f$ must be negative in the region where you look for a null-geodesic, otherwise there isn't one. The two values of square root correspond to different orientations of the same null-geodesic. Pick one and try to solve the nonlinear ODE of first order $x'(t)=\sqrt{-f(x(t))}$. Depending on $f$, it may be easy or hopeless.

Finding *geodesics* is a very different matter, because the relevant ODE is of the 2nd order instead of 1st. The [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity) to which Edward Hughes linked gives this equation,  but one shouldn't expect an explicit solution unless $f$ is very special.